# Using #define one time for multiple source files

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c-preprocessor

Is there a way in Visual C++ to #define something in a cpp file and have it defined in other cpp files as well?

Comment: Is there some reason you don't put it in a header file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are at least two options:

- Put the definition into a header file and include that header file in all the source files in which you need the definition
- Use [the `/D` compiler option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8(v=VS.100).aspx) to define the macro (this can also be set in the project properties under **C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions**)

Answer (score 3):

#### definitions.h:

```
#define foo bar
```

#### class.h:

```
#include "definitions.h"
```

Comment: #ifndef _DEFINITIONS_H
#define _DEFINITIONS_H

#define foo bar
#endif

Comment: @ebasconp:  Include guards aren't strictly necessary in this case since macros can be redefined so long as the new definition is identical to the previous definition (if you include the header twice, both definitions will obviously be identical).

Answer (score 1):

#define in a header (.h) file and #include that in all your .cpp files.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has mentioned the pre-processor setting in project properties already.

But you can also select only a few of the .cpp that you want the definition in and then right click on those and go to properties, then: **C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions**

It will define the defines for those .cpp files only and not your whole project.