# Visual Studio 2017 - Is it possible set pre-processor defines at the same time for debug and release configuration?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, release

I use Visual Studio for my C/C++ projects and I'm facing with a problem: when I create a new project, I use the debug configuration and add my pre-processor defines that I need. When I switch to release configuration I need to copy/paste the defines from debug to release configuration tab. So I'd like to know if it's possible, when I create a new project, add my pre-processor defines only one time, for debug and release configuration.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

> Visual Studio 2017 - Is it possible set pre-processor defines at the same time for debug and release configuration?

AFAIK, on the Properties window of Visual Studio, it seems there is no such way you can set pre-processor defines at the same time for debug and release configuration, but you can put the definition into a header file and include that header file in all the source files in which you need the definition:

**definitions.h:**

```
#define foo bar
```

**class.h:**

```
#include "definitions.h"
```

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946540/using-define-one-time-for-multiple-source-files) for some more details.

Hope this helps.